# OpenSSL: Trouble creating a public/private keypair using 64 bit DSA with SHA1 encryption

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl

I am trying to do Single Sign-On with SAML in order to embed a web app into my site. The documentation for the web app instructs me to create a public/private keypair:

> create a public/private keypair (using 64 bit DSA with SHA1 encryption)

After scouring Google on how to do this with Linux/OpenSSL I concocted the following commands:

```
sudo openssl dsaparam -out dsaparam.pem 64
sudo openssl gendsa -out private_key.pem dsaparam.pem
sudo openssl dsa -in private_key.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public_key.crt
```

Then it says to "Import the public key" that was created. But when I do it says that the public key is invalid.

So now I'm here asking for a sanity check. Did I create these keys correctly or am I noobing it up (and if so, what should I change)?

Thanks!
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key sizes for DSA should be 2048 or 3072 bits. 1024 bits is getting weak. openssl still accepts 512 bit DSA keys, but those are not secure. 64 bit is just plain impossible, since that is even shorter than the SHA1 digest size.

Comment: I thought 64 bit was odd because I read that the minimum should be 1024 bits various places.